# How to create for loop in xpath selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been working on this code to scrape the titles of search results from a wikipedia search. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?cirrusUserTesting=glent_m0&search=1st+indochinese+war&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1")

x = 1
while x != 10:
    headerxpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[3]/ul/li[{}]/div[1]/a'.format(x)
    seekheader = driver.find_element_by_xpath(headerxpath)
    print(seekheader.text)

    x = x + 1
```

The issue is that I am not sure how I can properly use syntax to put it into a for loop. So rather than it print e.g. first 10 results it prints all of the results. I wouldn't be able to **x != large number** either as that would cause the code to fail once it's collected the final title.

Hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should print all headers (341 results specifically) in a `for` loop. After you `get` the url do the following - this is the **CSS Selector** way:

```
#click the last "View" button at the bottom of the page so you can get all results on one page
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.mw-search-pager-bottom > a:last-of-type"))).click()

#css matching each of the 341 results
seekheader = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.mw-search-result-heading > a")))

for header in seekheader:
    print(header.text)
```

If you find it easier to work with **xpath**, just define these instead of the respective lines above:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='mw-search-pager-bottom']/a[last()]"))).click()
```

and

```
seekheader = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mw-search-result-heading']/a")))
```

Add these imports for wait conditions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just wondering though, how would I be able to actually print just the headers rather than the title and description for each document

Comment: Oh sorry, that's what you are after. Let me have a look.

Comment: Thanks would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Updated `seekheader` definition. You should get only headers now.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it :)